# AngularJS - Get JSON Attribute and display it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a bootstrap model with ng-repeat in it. It displays the JSON Data.
Now I want to click a team (teamname) and display it in the console.log . But, my problem is I cant get the teams.team (the team name)...

Do you have any idea how to handle this?

**app.js**

```
app.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {
   $scope.$on('modal', function (event, args) {
      $http.get('../data/teams.json').then(function (response) {
         var teams = response.data.teams;
         var teamsArray = [];
         for (var p  in  teams) {
              var d = teams[p];
              teamsArray.push(d);
         }
         $scope.teamSelected = function () {
              console.log("Clicked" + teams.team)
         };
         $scope.teams = teamsArray;
      });
   }) 
}]);
```

**modal.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:team | limitTo: paginationLimit()" ng-click="teamSelected(teams.team)">
    <div class="row pad-team-selection-view">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default team-selection-view">
            <img ng-src="{{ team.logo }}" width="18" height="18" class="img-logo">{{ team.team }}
         </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**teams.json**

```
{
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "league": "1. Bundesliga",
      "team": "FC Augsburg",
      "country": "Deutschland",
      "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b5/Logo_FC_Augsburg.svg"
    },
```

Comment: Check my answer that exactly works for you.

Comment: Sorry, but the other answer was in more detail :(

Comment: @WilliamHampshire If an accepted answer on StackOverflow is so important to you i'll give it to you :)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ng-repeat` div where you are passing in teams.team, you actually already have the team object so you can just pass in team. Also, make sure that team is an input to your teamSelected function like this:

HTML:

```
ng-click="teamSelected(team)"
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.teamSelected = function (team) {
  console.log("Clicked" + team.team)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the `ng-click` parameter

replace

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:team | limitTo: paginationLimit()" ng-click="teamSelected(teams.team)">
   <div class="row pad-team-selection-view">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default team-selection-view">
          <img ng-src="{{ team.logo }}" width="18" height="18" class="img-logo">{{ team.team }}
       </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:team | limitTo: paginationLimit()" ng-click="teamSelected(team)">
    <div class="row pad-team-selection-view">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default team-selection-view">
           <img ng-src="{{ team.logo }}" width="18" height="18" class="img-logo">{{ team.team }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

where you see that we have `ng-click="teamSelected(team)"` and replace this below code in controller

```
$scope.teamSelected = function () {
    console.log("Clicked" + teams.team)
};
```

with this code

```
$scope.teamSelected = function (obj) {
    console.log("Clicked" + obj.team)
};
```

Comment: You are my HERO! :)